# prove that the limit is infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to prove that the following limit is infinity?

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1{\sqrt x}\cdot \cos\left(\frac1x\right)$$

---

**Edit:**
Sorry I made a mistake, I want to prove that for each M>0 the given function is bigger than M when close to 0 from the right.

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital?

Comment: This limit isn't infinity because $\cos(1/x)$ oscillates.  The limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

We have that as $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n} \to 0$

$$\frac1{\sqrt x}\cdot \cos\left(\frac1x\right)=\sqrt{2\pi n} \to \infty$$

but for $x_n=\frac{2}{\pi n} \to 0$

$$\frac1{\sqrt x}\cdot \cos\left(\frac1x\right)=0$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I want to prove that for each M>0 the given function is bigger than M when close to 0 from the right.

Comment: @dan The way to prove that is to consider $x_n=1/2\pi n$ since the expression tends to infinity it becomes bigger than any $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}, n = 1, 2, \ldots, $, and $y_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi + \pi/2}, n = 1, 2, \ldots$. Then
\begin{align*}
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}}\cos(1/x_n) = +\infty. \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y_n}}\cos(1/y_n) = 0.
\end{align*}

Hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I want to prove that for each M>0 the given function is bigger than M when close to 0 from the right.